# Filling triangles in Matplotlib triplot with individual colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, delaunay

Is it possible to plot a list of triangles generated by scipy.spatial.Delaunay using pyplot's triplot function so that each triangle can be drawn and filled with an individual color? The basic python script I've created is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.image as mpimg  

h = 300
w = 1000

npts = 30

pts = np.zeros((npts,2))
pts[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,w,npts)
pts[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,h,npts)
tri = Delaunay(pts)

plt.xlim(0, w)
plt.ylim(0, h)

# Determine the color used for each triangle based upon the orthocenter
# of the triangle and the corresponding pixel color in a background image.

centers = np.sum(pts[tri.simplices], axis=1, dtype='int')/3.0
colors = [img[y,x] for x,y in centers]

# This plots the edges of each triangle with no fill. I'd like to 
# include the colors list to plot a fill for each.

plt.triplot(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy())

plt.show()
```

Is there some argument to triplot where I can pass the colors list which contains the color for the corresponding triangle. I'm sure I can draw each triangle in a loop, using the appropriate fill color, but it be good if there was a more elegant and faster method.

Answer (score 11):

The functionality you're looking for is included in [`pyplot.tripcolor`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tripcolor_demo.html).

From its documentation, you'll see that it is "smart" and tries to guess whether you have specified colors for the points or for the triangles:

> The next argument must be *C*, the array of color values, either
>   one per point in the triangulation if color values are defined at
>   points, or one per triangle in the triangulation if color values
>   are defined at triangles. If there are the same number of points
>   and triangles in the triangulation it is assumed that color
>   values are defined at points; to force the use of color values at
>   triangles use the kwarg *facecolors*=C instead of just *C*.

To continue with your example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

h = 300
w = 1000
npts = 500
pts = np.zeros((npts,2))
pts[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,w,npts)
pts[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,h,npts)
tri = Delaunay(pts)
plt.xlim(0, w)
plt.ylim(0, h)
centers = np.sum(pts[tri.simplices], axis=1, dtype='int')/3.0
colors = np.array([ (x-w/2.)**2 + (y-h/2.)**2 for x,y in centers])
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Here I merely based the color on the distance between the center of the triangle and the center of the image (because I don't have a suitable image).

[image]