# Tricontour with triangle values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to produce a tricontour plot [similar to these](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tricontour_demo.html) with matplotlib. The difference between these examples and my situation is that I don't have the values of my function in the grid points: they are defined in my triangles (e.g. in the centroid of each triangle).

I would like to plot the result of a finite volume simulation, where the values are defined for each control volume, not for each grid point.

I suppose one simple solution would be to average the values at each grid point. I would like to know if there are any more direct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but `tripcolor` function is designed for this use case (value defined at triangle centroid)

See for instance:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/tripcolor_demo.html

Comment: Yes, I actually found out this by looking at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245327. `tripcolor` does exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, perfect then, and thanks for the feedback. (Do not hesitate to answer your own questions, it can be useful for someone)

Comment: Sure, I usually do answer my own questions, if nobody comes with a better answer. You were faster than me. By the way, I'm also looking for a true 3d plot based on a triangulation, and did not find anything useful. Unless you can link to a simple solution, I'll probably post a new question about this soon. It sounds strange to me that nobody else has these kind of needs.