# matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor how to fill triangles with random RGB colors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Say I have a bunch of triangles, I know how to draw them using `matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor`, I want to know how to fill the individual triangles with completely random RGB colors from the entire RGB color space (all 16777216 colors) unrelated to x, y whatsoever, how to get this done?

I have this:
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251611/16383578)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from random import random, randbytes

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery-nogrid')

pts = np.zeros((360,2))
pts[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,1920,360)
pts[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,1080,360)
tri = Delaunay(pts)
plt.xlim(0, 1920)
plt.ylim(0, 1080)
centers = np.sum(pts[tri.simplices], axis=1, dtype='int')/3.0
colors = np.array([ (x-960)**2 + (y-540)**2 for x,y in centers])
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
l = centers.shape[0]

colors = np.random.random(size=l)
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

They are working, but the color variations of the two examples are too small.

The first generates something like this:

[image]

The colors are not random at all.

The second generates this:

[image]

There is little variation of colors in the second image.

I have tried a number of methods, all of them failed:

```
colors = np.random.random((l, 3))
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [tuple(randbytes(3)) for i in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [tuple(randbytes(4)) for i in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [tuple([random() for i in range(3)]) for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [tuple([random() for i in range(4)]) for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [randbytes(3).hex() for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = [randbytes(4).hex() for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = ['#'+randbytes(3).hex() for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

colors = ['#'+randbytes(4).hex() for j in range(l)]
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The first seven raise `ValueError: Collections can only map rank 1 arrays`.

The last two raise `TypeError: Image data of dtype <U6 cannot be converted to float`.

How to properly do this? Exactly what should be put into `facecolors`? The official documentation is extremely vague about what it should be.

---

For completeness' sake, my intention is to:

```
from PIL import Image

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, figsize=(19.2,10.8), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_axis_off()
...
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.box(False)
Image.frombytes('RGB', fig.canvas.get_width_height(), fig.canvas.tostring_rgb())
```

---

I was able to get this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from random import random, randbytes

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery-nogrid')

points = np.zeros((360,2))
points[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,1920,360)
points[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,1080,360)
triangles = points[Delaunay(points).simplices]

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, figsize=(19.2,10.8), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_axis_off()
for triangle in triangles:
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(triangle, edgecolor='#c0c0c0', facecolor='#'+randbytes(3).hex(), fill=True))

plt.xlim(0, 1920)
plt.ylim(0, 1080)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.box(False)
fig.canvas.draw()
Image.frombytes('RGB', fig.canvas.get_width_height(), fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()).show()
```

But my code is obviously much less efficient than `tripcolor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to avoid using `tripcolor` alltogether, unless you need some of it's specific functionality? You can create your own `PolyCollection` from the Delauny triangulation, which is a lot more flexible regarding formatting.

```py
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from copy import copy

n_points = 360
pts = np.random.randint(0, 1920, (n_points, 2)).astype(np.float32)

tri = Delaunay(pts)

vertices = np.stack((
    tri.points[tri.simplices, 0], # x
    tri.points[tri.simplices, 1], # y
), axis=-1)


collection = PolyCollection(vertices, edgecolor="k")
collection.set_facecolor(np.random.rand(len(vertices), 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8), facecolor="w")

ax.add_collection(copy(collection))
ax.autoscale_view()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around it is to create a colormap that generates random colors, independently of the values you have assigned to `facecolors` or `C`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

class RandomColors(Colormap):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __call__(self, X, alpha=None, bytes=False):
        # randomly generate an RGBA [N x 4] matrix of colors
        # where N is the number of elements of X
        # X is what we assigne to `facecolors` or `C`
        X = np.atleast_1d(X)
        col = np.random.random((X.shape[0], 4))
        # set alpha=1
        col[:, -1] = 1
        return col


plt.figure()
pts = np.zeros((360,2))
pts[:,0] = np.random.randint(0,1920,360)
pts[:,1] = np.random.randint(0,1080,360)
tri = Delaunay(pts)
plt.xlim(0, 1920)
plt.ylim(0, 1080)
centers = np.sum(pts[tri.simplices], axis=1, dtype='int')/3.0

# Don't really care about what's in this array: our custom colormap
# is going to ignore it!
colors = np.ones(centers.shape[0])
# instantiate the colormap
cmap = RandomColors()
plt.tripcolor(pts[:,0], pts[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), facecolors=colors, cmap=cmap, edgecolors='k')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]